# Like and google +1 buttons on website

Tags: wordpress, web, facebook-like

I have a website (testing) on wordpress and installed a plugin to show google +1 button for each post. And when someone press it, the number increases with one.

My Question is Where this +1 button points ? As far as i know +1 is for google plus posts on pages on profile but my website post is **NOWHERE** on google plus(page) it is just on my website and the same for facebook like button (where it points)

I hope you understand what i am talking about.Please help

Comment: I am asking a genuine question, and i really need help , then why someone making negative votes for it? If you don't know what i am asking then leave it

Comment: Pls make ur question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a "+1s" page in Google+ user profiles, you can find your own here: https://plus.google.com/yourgoogleplususeridhere/plusones

Seems like it is not visible to other users from the beginning on. You can change that in the settings, but as an external user you probably don´t see other users +1s if they don´t want to. Maybe that´s your problem.

To be more clear on this: If you are not in someones circles and they have furthermore disabled to publicly share their +1s, you might not see them on Google+, although they are there. Somewhere.

Comment: ohh.. thanks bro.. you solved all my confusion... Thank you very much...!